# Интерактивные карты svg

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Сделал карту Беларуси и разбил по районам, не подскажете, как еще сделать разбивку по областям?

```css
/*Карта на главной странице*/
.map svg {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /* margin: 0 auto; */
    display: block;
    /* padding-top: 0; */
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: -35px;
}
.map g {
    fill: #c1df7f;
    stroke: #95BB47;
    stroke-width: 1.9px;
}
.map g:hover {
    fill: #29910d!important;
    cursor: help;
}
.map circle{
    fill:#FF6163!important;
}
.info_panel {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .8);
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.info_panel::first-line {
    font-weight: bold;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="0 -21.6 761 919" style="enable-background:new 0 -21.6 761 919;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="sar">
      <polygon id="hrodzenski-raion" points="75,265 65,265 60,270 60,275 55,280 45,280 40,285 40,280 35,275 35,265 30,260 30,240 25,235 25,225 30,225 35,230 45,230 50,225 60,225 65,230 75,230"/>
    </g>
    <g id="sic">
      <polygon id="berastavitski-raion" points="40,285 40,290 45,295 45,310 50,315 60,305 60,285 55,280 45,280"/>
    </g>
    <g id="cal">
      <polygon id="mastouski-raion" points="60,285 65,285 70,280 75,280 85,290 85,295 100,295 105,290 110,295 115,290 110,285 110,275 105,270 100,275 90,265 85,270 80,270 75,265 65,265 60,270 60,275 55,280"/>
    </g>
    <g id="bas">
      <polygon id="vaukavyski-raion" points="85,300 90,305 90,310 95,315 95,320 90,325 75,310 65,310 60,305 60,285 65,285 70,280 75,280 85,290"/>
    </g>
    <g id="pug">
      <polygon id="zelvenski-raion" points="115,290 120,295 115,300 120,305 115,310 110,310 105,315 105,320 95,320 95,315 90,310 90,305 85,300 85,295 100,295 105,290 110,295"/>
    </g>
    <g id="cam">
      <polygon id="svislatski-raion" points="50,315 50,340 55,340 60,335 65,340 75,340 80,345 85,340 85,330 90,325 75,310 65,310 60,305"/>
    </g>
    <g id="mol">
      <polygon id="slonimski-raion" points="105,320 105,325 110,330 125,330 125,325 130,320 135,320 140,315 140,295 130,295 125,290 120,295 115,300 120,305 115,310 110,310 105,315"/>
    </g>
    <g id="abr">
      <polygon id="dziatlauski-raion" points="140,295 145,290 145,285 150,280 150,270 145,265 145,260 140,260 135,255 130,255 120,265 115,265 110,270 110,275 110,285 115,290 120,295 125,290 130,295"/>
    </g>
    <g id="laz">
      <polygon id="shchuchynski-raion" points="115,265 115,260 110,255 110,250 105,245 105,240 100,240 95,235 95,225 90,220 85,225 80,225 75,230 75,265 80,270 85,270 90,265 100,275 105,270 110,275 110,270"/>
    </g>
    <g id="umb">
      <polygon id="voranauski-raion" points="95,225 100,220 100,210 105,205 115,205 125,195 130,195 135,190 140,195 140,200 134.7,205 140,210 135,215 135,220 125,220 110,235 105,235 105,240 100,240 95,235"/>
    </g>
    <g id="mar">
      <polygon id="lidski-raion" points="135,255 140,250 140,240 145,235 145,230 135,220 125,220 110,235 105,235 105,240 105,245 110,250 110,255 115,260 115,265 120,265 130,255"/>
    </g>
    <g id="tos">
      <polygon id="navagrudski-raion" points="150,280 160,280 160,270 170,260 175,260 180,255 185,255 185,250 180,245 180,240 175,240 160,240 155,235 145,235 140,240 140,250 135,255 140,260 145,260 145,265 150,270"/>
    </g>
    <g id="emi">
     <polygon id="karelitski-raion" points="160,280 175,280 180,285 185,285 190,280 195,280 195,260 190,255 185,255 180,255 175,260 170,260 160,270"/>
    </g>
    <g id="fri">
      <polygon id="iueuski-raion" points="140,210 145,210 150,205 155,205 155,200 160,200 165,205 170,205 170,210 175,210 175,215 185,215 185,220 190,220 190,225 180,235 180,240 160,240 155,235 145,235 145,230 135,220 135,215"/>
    </g>
    <g id="ven">
      <polygon id="ashmianski-raion" points="170,205 175,200 175,170 160,170 155,165 150,165 145,170 145,180 140,185 145,190 150,190 155,195 155,200 160,200 165,205"/>
    </g>
    <g id="tre">
      <polygon id="smargonski-raion" points="175,200 185,200 195,190 195,185 200,180 200,175 205,170 205,160 200,160 195,155 195,150 190,145 185,145 180,150 180,155 185,160 180,165 175,165 175,170"/>
    </g>
    <g id="lom">
      <polygon id="astravetski-raion" points="185,145 185,135 175,125 170,130 160,130 155,135 155,140 150,145 150,165 155,165 160,170 175,170 175,165 180,165 185,160 180,155 180,150"/>
    </g>



    <g id="lom">
            <polygon id="pastauski-raion" points="175,125 180,120 180,115 185,110 205,110 205,105 210,100 240,100 245,105 245,115 250,120 250,125 235,125 230,125 225,130 190,130 185,135"/>
    </g>
    <g id="">
            <polygon id="braslauski-raion" points="215,100 210,95 195,95 190,90 195,85 195,75 200,70 200,60 210,60 225,45 235,45 240,50 250,50 250,55 240,65 240,75 245,80 240,85 230,85 225,90 225,100"/>
    </g>
    <g id="">
            <polygon id="sharkaushchynski-raion" points="245,80 275,80 280,85 280,95 275,95 270,100 265,95 250,95 250,100 245,105 240,100 225,100 225,90 230,85 240,85"/>
    </g>
    <g id="">
            <polygon id="dokshytski-raion" points="235,125 235,130 240,135 245,135 250,140 250,145 255,145 260,150 260,155 265,160 290,160 290,150 295,145 300,145 300,135 285,120 255,120 250,125"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="hlybotski-raion" points="290,125 290,120 295,115 295,100 300,95 295,90 290,95 280,95 275,95 270,100 265,95 250,95 250,100 245,105 245,115 250,120 250,125 255,120 285,120"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="miorski-raion" points="295,90 295,80 300,75 300,70 290,70 280,60 275,60 275,50 270,45 265,50 255,50 255,50 250,50 250,55 240,65 240,75 245,80 275,80 280,85 280,95 290,95"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="verhniadzvinski-raion" points="275,60 280,60 290,70 300,70 310,60 305,55 305,50 300,45 300,35 305,30 305,20 300,20 295,25 290,20 290,15 280,15 270,25 270,30 265,35 260,35 255,40 255,50 265,50 270,45 275,50"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="lepelski-raion" points="290,160 300,170 305,165 305,160 315,160 320,155 325,155 330,150 335,150 335,145 330,140 340,130 340,120 330,120 325,120 320,125 310,125 300,135 300,145 295,145 290,150"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="chashnitski-raion" points="315,160 315,165 320,170 325,170 330,165 360,165 365,160 365,155 360,150 360,140 355,135 355,130 340,130 330,140 335,145 335,150 330,150 325,155 320,155"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="talachynski-raion" points="360,165 360,185 355,190 355,200 360,200 370,190 385,190 390,195 395,195 395,185 400,180 400,175 395,170 390,170 385,165 385,160 365,160"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="arshanski-raion" points="395,190 405,190 410,195 420,195 425,190 425,185 430,180 430,175 420,165 425,160 425,155 430,150 430,145 420,145 410,145 405,150 405,155 400,160 385,160 385,165 390,170 395,170 400,175 400,180 395,185"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="dubrovenski-raion" points="430,180 435,185 440,185 445,180 455,180 460,175 455,175 455,170 460,165 460,155 450,155 445,150 440,150 435,145 430,145 430,150 425,155 425,160 420,165 430,175"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="sennenski-raion" points="360,140 370,130 375,130 380,125 390,125 395,130 400,130 405,135 415,135 420,140 420,145 410,145 405,150 405,155 400,160 385,160 365,160 365,155 360,150"/>
        </g>    
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="lioznenski-raion" points="435,145 435,140 440,135 440,130 445,130 445,125 450,120 450,110 445,105 435,105 425,115 420,115 415,120 415,135 420,140 420,145"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="vitsebski-raion" points="445,105 440,100 440,90 445,85 445,65 440,65 435,70 430,75 420,75 420,80 410,90 390,90 385,95 385,105 390,110 390,125 395,130 400,130 405,135 415,135 415,120 420,115 425,115 435,105"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="beshankovitski-raion" points="385,105 380,105 375,110 375,115 365,115 360,120 360,115 355,115 350,110 350,105 345,100 345,115 340,120 340,130 355,130 355,135 360,140 370,130 375,130 380,125 390,125 390,110"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="shumilinski-raion" points="385,95 380,95 375,90 375,80 365,70 355,80 350,80 340,90 335,90 345,100 350,105 350,110 355,115 360,115 360,120 365,115 375,115 375,110 380,105 385,105"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="ushatski-raion" points="335,90 325,100 310,100 305,105 295,105 295,115 290,120 290,125 300,135 310,125 320,125 325,120 340,120 345,115 345,100"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="polatski-raion" points="365,70 365,55 360,55 355,50 350,50 345,55 340,55 335,60 310,60 300,70 300,75 295,80 295,90 300,95 295,100 295,105 305,105 310,100 325,100 335,90 340,90 350,80 355,80"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="haradotski-raion" points="435,70 430,65 430,60 420,50 415,50 410,45 385,45 380,50 370,50 365,55 365,70 375,80 375,90 380,95 385,95 390,90 410,90 420,80 420,75 430,75"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="rasonski-raion" points="355,50 355,45 360,40 360,35 355,30 345,30 340,25 335,25 325,35 320,35 320,30 315,25 315,20 305,20 305,30 300,35 300,45 305,50 305,55 310,60 335,60 340,55 345,55 350,50"/>
            </g>



        <g id="">
            <polygon id="horatski-raion" points="460,175 465,180 465,195 465,200 460,205 450,205 445,210 440,210 435,205 430,200 425,200 420,195 425,190 425,185 430,180 435,185 440,185 445,180 455,180"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="drybinski-raion" points="460,205 460,215 465,220 460,225 450,225 445,220 430,220 425,215 430,210 430,200 440,210 445,210 450,205"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="mstsislauski-raion" points="460,225 465,230 465,240 470,240 475,235 490,235 495,230 495,215 490,215 485,210 480,210 470,200 465,200 460,205 460,215 465,220"/>v
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="shklouski-raion" points="395,195 395,200 390,205 390,210 395,215 405,215 410,220 420,220 425,215 430,210 430,200 425,200 420,195 410,195 405,190 395,190"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kruhlianski-raion" points="390,210 375,210 370,215 360,215 360,200 370,190 385,190 390,195 395,195 395,200 390,205"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="bialynitski-raion" points="360,215 355,220 355,235 360,240 360,250 365,245 370,245 375,250 380,250 380,240 395,225 395,215 390,210 375,210 370,215"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="klichauski-raion" points="360,250 350,250 345,255 340,255 335,260 330,260 330,275 335,280 335,285 340,290 345,290 350,285 355,285 375,265 380,265 380,250 375,250 370,245 365,245"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="asipovitski-raion" points="330,275 330,265 325,260 315,260 305,270 300,270 300,280 305,285 300,290 285,290 285,295 290,300 299.5,300 305,305 320,305 335,290 340,290 335,285 335,280"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="hluski-raion" points="310,305 310,315 305,320 305,325 300,330 300,335 295,340 300,345 325,345 325,340 330,335 330,330 330,320 320,310 320,305"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="babruiski-raion" points="330,330 340,330 345,325 360,325 365,320 375,320 370,315 370,305 365,300 350,300 340,290 335,290 320,305 320,310 330,320"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kirauski-raion" points="370,305 375,305 380,300 380,295 375,290 380,285 385,285 385,275 380,270 380,265 375,265 355,285 350,285 345,290 340,290 350,300 365,300"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="byhauski-raion" points="385,285 390,285 395,290 400,290 400,295 410,295 420,285 425,285 425,275 430,270 430,260 425,255 405,255 400,250 380,250 380,270 385,275"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="mahiliouski-raion" points="425,255 425,250 420,245 425,240 425,235 430,230 435,225 435,220 430,220 425,215 420,220 410,220 405,215 395,215 395,225 380,240 380,250 400,250 405,255"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="chavuski-raion" points="465,240 460,240 455,245 455,250 450,255 445,255 440,260 435,260 430,265 430,260 425,255 425,250 420,245 425,240 425,235 435,225 435,220 445,220 450,225 460,225 465,230"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="cherykauski-raion" points="455,250 455,265 460,270 460,275 480,275 485,270 485,260 475,250 470,250 465,245 465,240 460,240 455,245"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="krychauski-raion" points="485,260 490,255 495,255 500,250 500,240 495,240 490,235 475,235 470,240 465,240 465,245 470,250 475,250"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="klimavitski-raion" points="500,240 515,240 520,245 525,245 530,250 530,260 515,275 490,275 485,270 485,260 490,255 495,255 500,250"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="khotsimski-raion" points="530,260 540,270 545,270 545,280 525,300 520,295 520,290 515,285 515,275"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kastsiukovitski-raion" points="525,300 515,310 500,310 490,300 485,300 485,295 490,290 490,275 515,275 515,285 520,290 520,295"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="krasnapolski-raion" points="485,300 475,300 470,305 455,305 450,300 450,290 460,280 460,275 480,275 485,270 490,275 490,290 485,295"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="slauharadski-raion" points="450,290 430,290 425,285 425,275 430,270 430,265 435,260 440,260 445,255 450,255 455,250 455,265 460,270 460,275 
            460,280"/>

            </g>


        <g id="">
            <polygon id="karmianski-raion" points="455,305 450,310 445,310 435,320 430,320 425,315 420,310 420,305 430,295 430,290 450,290 450,300"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="chacherski-raion" points="470,305 470,310 465,315 465,320 460,325 460,330 455,330 445,340 445,345 440,345 435,340 435,335 420,320 425,315 430,320 435,320 445,310 450,310 455,305"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="rahachouski-raion" points="420,320 415,320 415,330 410,325 405,325 400,320 375,320 370,315 370,305 375,305 380,300 380,295 375,290 380,285 390,285 395,290 400,290 400,295 410,295 420,285 425,285 430,290 430,295 420,305 420,310 425,315"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="zhlobinski-raion" points="415,330 410,335 410,340 405,345 405,360 395,360 390,355 385,355 380,350 375,350 360,335 360,330 355,325 360,325 365,320 400,320 405,325 410,325"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="svetlahorski-raion" points="390,355 385,360 385,375 380,370 370,370 365,375 360,375 355,370 355,365 350,360 345,360 345,355 350,350 345,345 345,340 340,335 340,330 345,325 355,325 360,330 360,335 375,350 380,350 385,355"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="aktsiabrski-raion" points="345,360 340,365 330,365 325,360 320,360 315,365 300,365 300,355 305,350 305,345 325,345 325,340 330,335 330,330 340,330 340,335 345,340 345,345 350,350 345,355"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="petrykauski-raion" points="300,365 295,370 295,375 285,385 285,400 290,405 290,410 305,410 310,405 315,405 320,400 335,400 335,390 330,385 330,380 335,375 335,365 330,365 325,360 320,360 315,365"/>
        </g>
        <g id="">
            <polygon id="zhytkavitski-raion" points="295,370 285,370 280,365 275,365 275,370 260,370 255,365 255,360 250,360 240,370 240,375 235,380 240,385 245,385 250,390 250,405 255,410 255,415 250,420 250,430 260,420 265,420 270,415 280,415 285,410 290,410 290,405 285,400 285,385 295,375"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="lelchytski-raion" points="250,430 250,450 260,450 260,460 265,460 270,455 280,455 290,445 295,445 295,450 300,455 305,455 310,450 310,440 320,430 320,420 315,415 310,415 305,410 285,410 280,415 270,415 265,420 260,420"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kalinkavitski-raion" points="365,430 370,425 370,420 385,405 375,395 380,390 380,385 385,380 385,375 380,370 370,370 365,375 360,375 355,370 355,365 350,360 345,360 340,365 335,365 335,375 330,380 330,385 335,390 335,400 345,400 355,410 355,415 365,425"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="mazyrski-raion" points="320,430 325,430 330,425 350,425 355,425 360,430 365,430 365,425 355,415 355,410 345,400 335,400 320,400 315,405 310,405 305,410 310,415 315,415 320,420"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="elski-raion" points="350,425 350,430 345,435 345,445 340,445 340,450 335,455 330,455 325,460 325,470 320,470 315,465 315,455 305,455 310,450 310,440 320,430 325,430 330,425"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="naraulianski-raion" points="345,445 345,455 350,460 350,470 360,470 370,460 375,460 380,465 390,465 380,455 380,450 370,440 370,435 365,435 365,430 360,430 355,425 350,425 350,430 345,435"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="khoinitski-raion" points="390,465 395,460 400,460 400,455 395,450 395,445 390,440 395,435 395,430 400,425 400,420 410,410 410,405 405,405 400,400 400,395 395,395 385,405 370,420 370,425 365,430 365,435 370,435 370,440 380,450 380,455"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="brahinski-raion" points="400,460 410,470 410,475 420,485 425,480 425,460 420,455 420,450 425,445 425,440 420,435 420,430 415,425 415,415 410,410 400,420 400,425 395,430 395,435 390,440 395,445 395,450 400,455"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="rechytski-raion" points="410,405 420,405 430,395 425,390 430,385 430,380 420,370 420,365 410,365 405,360 395,360 390,355 385,360 385,380 380,385 380,390 375,395 385,405 395,395 400,395 400,400 405,405"/>
</g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="loeuski-raion" points="425,440 430,435 430,425 445,410 445,405 440,405 430,395 420,405 410,405 410,410 415,415 415,425 420,430 420,435"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="buda-kashaliouski-raion" points="420,365 425,365 430,360 440,360 445,355 445,345 440,345 435,340 435,335 420,320 415,320 415,330 410,335 410,340 405,345 405,360 410,365"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="homelski-raion" points="445,355 460,370 460,390 470,400 465,405 465,410 460,410 455,405 445,405 440,405 425,390 430,385 430,380 420,370 420,365 425,365 430,360 440,360"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="vetkauski-raion" points="460,370 460,365 465,360 470,360 480,350 480,340 475,335 475,330 465,320 460,325 460,330 455,330 445,340 445,345 445,355"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="dobrushski-raion" points="480,350 480,355 485,360 480,365 480,380 490,390 490,395 495,400 495,405 485,405 480,400 470,400 460,390 460,370 460,365 465,360 470,360"/>
            </g>



            <g id="">
            <polygon id="salihorski-raion" points="235,380 230,375 230,370 225,365 225,345 220,340 225,335 230,335 230,325 250,325 255,330 260,330 265,335 265,345 270,350 270,355 275,360 275,365 275,370 260,370 255,365 255,360 250,360 240,370 240,375"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="liubanski-raion" points="260,330 270,320 275,320 280,325 285,325 290,330 295,330 300,335 295,340 300,345 305,345 305,350 300,355 300,365 295,370 285,370 280,365 275,365 275,360 270,355 270,350 265,345 265,335"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="staradarozhski-raion" points="275,320 275,310 280,305 280,300 270,300 270,295 275,290 275,285 280,285 285,290 285,295 290,300 299.5,300 305,305 310,305 310,315 305,320 305,325 300,330 300,335 295,330 290,330 285,325 280,325"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="puhavitski-raion" points="270,295 265,290 260,290 255,285 255,280 260,275 255,270 255,265 250,260 250,255 260,255 265,250 265,245 270,245 280,255 285,255 290,260 295,260 300,255 310,265 305,270 300,270 300,280 305,285 300,290 285,290 280,285 275,285 275,290"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="chervenski-raion" points="270,245 275,240 285,240 295,230 305,230 310,225 315,225 315,230 320,235 320,245 325,250 325,260 315,260 310,265 300,255 295,260 290,260 285,255 280,255"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="biarezinski-raion" points="315,225 320,220 330,220 335,215 345,215 355,225 355,235 360,240 360,250 350,250 345,255 340,255 335,260 330,260 330,265 325,260 325,250 320,245 320,235 315,230"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="krupski-raion" points="335,215 335,205 330,200 330,190 325,185 325,170 330,165 360,165 360,185 355,190 355,200 360,200 360,215 355,220 355,225 345,215"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="barysauski-raion" points="310,225 305,220 305,215 290,200 290,190 285,185 290,180 280,170 275,165 275,160 290,160 300,170 305,165 305,160 315,160 315,165 320,170 325,170 325,185 330,190 330,200 335,205 335,215 330,220 320,220 315,225"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="smaliavitski-raion" points="275,240 275,230 270,225 270,220 265,215 270,210 275,210 285,200 290,200 305,215 305,220 310,225 305,230 295,230 285,240"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="lagoiski-raion" points="265,215 260,210 255,210 255,205 245,195 250,190 250,165 260,155 265,160 275,160 275,165 290,180 285,185 290,190 290,200 285,200 275,210 270,210"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="miadzelski-raion" points="250,145 250,150 245,155 240,155 235,160 230,160 225,155 220,155 215,150 200,150 195,155 195,150 190,145 185,145 185,135 190,130 225,130 230,125 235,125 235,130 240,135 245,135 250,140"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="vileiski-raion" points="200,180 210,180 215,185 220,185 225,190 235,190 240,195 245,195 250,190 250,165 260,155 260,150 255,145 250,145 250,150 245,155 240,155 235,160 230,160 225,155 220,155 215,150 200,150 195,155 200,160 205,160 205,170 200,175"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="maladzechanski-raion" points="240,195 240,205 230,215 215,215 210,210 205,210 190,195 195,190 195,185 200,180 210,180 215,185 220,185 225,190 235,190"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="minski-raion" points="230,215 230,220 225,225 225,230 230,235 235,235 245,245 245,250 250,255 260,255 265,250 265,245 270,245 275,240 275,230 270,225 270,220 265,215 260,210 255,210 255,205 245,195 240,195 240,205"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="valozhynski-raion" points="225,230 220,230 215,235 190,235 185,230 190,225 190,220 185,220 185,215 175,215 175,210 170,210 170,205 175,200 185,200 190,195 205,210 210,210 215,215 230,215 230,220 225,225"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="staubtsouski-raion" points="195,280 195,285 215,285 215,280 220,275 220,265 215,260 215,250 220,245 220,240 215,235 190,235 185,230 180,235 180,245 185,250 185,255 190,255 195,260"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="dziarzhynski-raion" points="220,270 225,270 230,265 240,265 245,260 245,255 250,255 245,250 245,245 235,235 230,235 225,230 220,230 215,235 220,240 220,245 215,250 215,260 220,265"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="uzdzenski-raion" points="215,280 220,285 230,285 235,290 240,285 245,285 250,280 255,280 260,275 255,270 255,265 250,260 250,255 245,255 245,260 240,265 230,265 225,270 220,270 220,275"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="slutski-raion" points="245,285 245,290 250,295 230,315 230,325 250,325 255,330 260,330 270,320 275,320 275,310 280,305 280,300 270,300 270,295 265,290 260,290 255,285 255,280 250,280"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kapylski-raion" points="225,335 215,325 215,320 210,315 210,310 215,305 215,285 215,280 220,285 230,285 235,290 240,285 245,285 245,290 250,295 230,315 230,325 230,335"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="niasvizhski-raion" points="185,285 185,290 180,295 180,300 185.3,305 200,305 205,310 210,310 215,305 215,285 195,285 195,280 190,280"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kletski-raion" points="190,305 195,310 185,320 190,325 190,335 195,330 200,330 210,340 220,340 225,335 215,325 215,320 210,315 210,310 205,310 200,305"/>
            </g>



            <g id="">
            <polygon id="baranavitski-raion" points="185.3,305 175,305 170,310 170,320 165,325 160,325 155,330 150,330 140,320 135,320 140,315 140,295 145,290 145,285 150,280 160,280 175,280 180,285 185,285 185,290 180,295 180,300"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="liahavitski-raion" points="155,330 155,335 165,345 165,350 175,340 180,340 185,335 190,335 190,325 185,320 195,310 190,305 175,305 170,310 170,320 165,325 160,325"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="hantsavitski-raion" points="165,350 175,360 185,360 190,365 195,365 200,370 205,365 205,355 215,345 220,345 225,345 220,340 210,340 200,330 195,330 190,335 185,335 180,340 175,340"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="luninetski-raion" points="200,370 195,370 190,375 190,380 195,385 195,390 200,395 205,395 210,400 250,400 250,390 245,385 240,385 235,380 230,375 230,370 225,365 225,345 215,345 205,355 205,365"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="stolinski-raion" points="210,400 205,405 200,405 195,410 190,410 185,415 190,420 190,425 195,430 205,430 210,435 230,435 235,440 235,445 240,450 250,450 250,430 250,420 255,415 255,410 250,405 250,400"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="pinski-raion" points="175,360 175,365 170,370 150,370 150,385 155,385 160,390 155,395 155,400 150,405 150,415 155,420 170,420 175,425 190,425 190,420 185,415 190,410 195,410 200,405 205,405 210,400 205,395 200,395 195,390 195,385 190,380 190,375 195,370 200,370 195,365 190,365 185,360"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="ivatsevichski-raion" points="150,375 145,370 140,370 135,365 130,365 115,350 105,350 105,340 115,330 125,330 125,325 130,320 135,320 140,320 150,330 155,330 155,335 165,345 165,350 175,360 175,365 170,370 150,370"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="ivanauski-raion" points="140,370 135,370 130,375 130,380 135,385 130,390 130,400 125,405 125,415 130,420 145,420 150,415 150,405 155,400 155,395 160,390 155,385 150,385 150,375 145,370"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="biarozauski-raion" points="130,375 115,375 110,380 100,380 95,375 95,370 95,365 90,360 90,355 95,350 105,350 115,350 130,365 135,365 140,370 135,370"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="pruzhanski-raion" points="95,370 90,370 85,375 80,370 75,370 70,375 65,375 55,365 55,360 50,355 50,350 50,340 55,340 60,335 65,340 75,340 80,345 85,340 85,330 90,325 95,320 105,320 105,325 110,330 115,330 105,340 105,350 95,350 90,355 90,360 95,365"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kamiznetski-raion" points="50,350 40,350 35,355 25,355 15,365 15,370 10,375 10,380 5,385 10,390 15,390 20,395 20,385 25,380 30,380 40,390 45,390 45,380 55,380 60,375 65,375 55,365 55,360 50,355"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="brestski-raion" points="20,395 25,400 30,400 30,405 35,410 35,415 30,420 30,435 25,440 25,455 30,460 30,450 35,445 40,445 40,435 45,430 45,425 50,420 50,415 55,410 60,410 50,400 50,395 45,390 40,390 30,380 25,380 20,385"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="zhabinkauski-raion" points="60,410 65,410 65,405 70,400 65,395 65,390 60,385 60,375 55,380 45,380 45,390 50,395 50,400"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="malarytski-raion" points="40,445 45,445 50,450 50,455 55,455 60,450 75,435 75,420 80,415 75,410 65,410 60,410 55,410 50,415 50,420 45,425 45,430 40,435"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="kobrynski-raion" points="75,420 95,420 100,415 100,410 95,405 95,380 100,380 95,375 95,370 90,370 85,375 80,370 75,370 70,375 60,375 60,385 65,390 65,395 70,400 65,405 65,410 75,410 80,415"/>
            </g>
            <g id="">
            <polygon id="drahichynski-raion" points="95,420 110,420 115,415 125,415 125,405 130,400 130,390 135,385 130,380 130,375 115,375 110,380 100,380 95,380 95,405 100,410 100,415"/>    
            </g>


        <circle id="horad-pinsk" cx="170" cy="400" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-baranavichy" cx="165" cy="305" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-zhodzina" cx="295" cy="210" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-babruisk" cx="345" cy="300" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-mahiliou" cx="410" cy="230" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-brest" cx="35" cy="405" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-vitsebsk" cx="400" cy="110" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-homel" cx="450" cy="375" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-hrodna" cx="40" cy="250" r="4"/>
        <circle id="horad-navapolatsk" cx="310" cy="75" r="4"/>
    <circle id="horad-minsk" cx="253" cy="231" r="8"/>
  </svg>
</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: код по областям у меня есть, не могу его сюда вставить, но как совместить регионы и области не понимаю

Comment: уточните, пожалуста. области входят в регионы как меньшие единицы деления? если да, то вставка кода областей выше кода регионов отристует области поверх регионов

Comment: @while1pass, речь о районах и областях, т.е. районы входят в области как меньшие единицы деления. Так что нужно вставлять код областей выше кода районов ) И, возможно, стоит сделать что бы границы районов, в том месте, где они совпадают с границами области, может быть были бы чуть меньше, дабы район был внутри области?

Comment: да, вы верно мыслите, области идут ниже по коду и перекрываются районами, с учетом видимых границы. на сколько понимаю, это дизайнерская проблема, например, на гугл-картах границы стран ваделены сплошным цветом, областей - пунктиром, районы - не отмечены вообще

Comment: сделал но у меня только граница територии страны выделилась а области нет

Comment: <g id="regions">
 
  <polygon id="hrodnenskaia-voblasts" points="200,160 195,155 195,150 190,145 185,145 185,135 175,125 170,130 160,130 155,135 155,140 150,145 150,165 145,170 145,180 140,185 145,190 150,190 155,195 155,200 155,205 150,205 145,210 140,210 134.7,205 140,200 140,195 135,190 130,195 125,195 115,205 105,205 100,210 100,220 95,225 90,220 85,225 80,225 75,230 65,230 60,225 50,225 45,230 35,230 30,225 25,225 25,235 30,240 30,260  "/>
<g>

вот такой код областей, их всего 6

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, Вам нужна примерно [такая карта](https://codepen.io/Rybak/pen/KmKqNR).
В одну группу нужно объединять область и входящие в неё регионы.
Примерно такая структура:

```
<svg id="map">
   <g class="oblast-group"> 
      <polygon class="oblast">
      <polygon class="region"/>
      <polygon class="region"/>
      <polygon class="region"/>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Область будет находиться под своими регионами.
А подсвечивать её можно при ховере на всё группу.